# why this code is not loading pages ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Guys What I am trying to do is load a page on navigation click with ajax and put some delay in it loading
when nothing is clicked I want load home page following loading animation with jquery and a delay with PHP code 
and if something on nav is clicked I want to load that particular file
but this code don't seem to be working

```
var res = {
    loader: $('<div />', {class: 'loader' } ),
    container: $('.content')
};

$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'templates/delay.php',
                beforeSend, function(){
                    res.container.append(res.loader);
                },
                success, function(){
                    res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
                    $('.content').load('templates/pages/home.php');
                }
            });
            $('ul#nav_a li a').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                url: 'templates/delay.php',
                beforeSend, function(){
                    res.container.append(res.loader);
                },
                success, function(){
                    res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
                    var page=$(this).attr('href');
                    $('.content').load('templates/pages/'+page+'.php');
                        return false;
                    });
            });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why do you want to run the delay timer on the server side? Seems totally unnecessary to me.

Comment: You're doing unworthy things. Why you did use ajax to delay. You don't need to do it. Just show loading, and request to server to get data that you want, and then put it to corresponding element. Finally, hide the loading. It's very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not discuss the code itself, but just improve it.

Try this code and tell me if you get what you want : ( comments inside the js code )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'templates/delay.php',     
        // old code : beforeSend,
        beforeSend: function(){
            res.container.append(res.loader);
        },
        // old code : success,
        success: function(){
            res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
            $('.content').load('templates/pages/home.php');
        }
        // beforeSend and success are keys with functions as values that's why we use ":" and not ","
        // the "," comma is used to separate ajax settings
    });
    $('ul#nav_a li a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'templates/delay.php',
            // old code : beforeSend,
            beforeSend: function(){
                res.container.append(res.loader);
            },
            // old code : success,
            success: function(){
                res.container.find(res.loader).remove();                    
                $('.content').load('templates/pages/'+page+'.php'); 
            // old code
            //  return false;
            //  });

            // we close our ajax.success function
            }
        })
        // old code
        // }

        // return false is used to prevent browser to run the a href that's why we use it in the a.click function and not inside the ajax block
        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Yes Your improved the code very good but still I got a problem with this website can you have look at it 
it live @ www.askasim.com

Comment: I think that I get your problem. It's the `var page = $(this).attr('href');` it should be outside the ajax block to work correctly. I edited my answer.

Comment: Now the problem is when we click a navigation button it will not hide the previous loaded content and show the loader on the top of that content

Comment: But how It works ? I see it, every time it load : http://www.askasim.com/templates/pages/undefined.php !

Comment: @akmozo I don't know how to answer this question like this. Do you realize that using ajax to delay is stupid or not?. Idiot.

Comment: @jewelnguyen8 Yes I agree with you because I don't know why Muhammad do that, and as I wrote I do just improve the code to work, and then we can discus other "problems".

Comment: brother its online you can visit it now

Comment: If it's working, we can pass to the question : why do you use ajax to delay ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = {
    loader: $('<div />', {class: 'loader' } ),
    container: $('.content')
};
$(document).ready(function(){
        res.container.append(res.loader);
        $('.content').load( "templates/pages/home.php", function() {
             res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
        });
        $('ul#nav_a li a').click(function(){
            var page=$(this).attr('href');
            $('.content').load( 'templates/pages/'+page+'.php', function() {
                res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
             });
        });
     }
 });
```

Just copy and paste it.